# You have letters: $A,A,C,D,E$ in a bag. You pick $3$ at random without putting them back. What is the total number of combinations you can make?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

You have letters: $A,A,C,D,E$ in a bag. You pick $3$ at random without putting them back. What is the total number of combinations you can make?

I am doing $\binom{5}{3}$, however, this results in $10$. I know this must be incorrect because these are the list of all combinations possible:
$[a,a,c],[a,a,d],[a,a,e],[a,c,d],[a,c,e],[a,d,e],[c,d,e]$

I would really appreciate someone showing me how this kind of problem is solved. It is basic but I can't seem to wrap my head around what's happening.

Comment: The answer is not ${5 \choose 3}$ because the letter $A$ appears two times. You can solve by splitting into two cases, in the first case consider all combinations with only one $A$ and  in the second case consider all combinations with two $A$'s.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. This does indeed get the right answer. However, I was unsure if it's possible to go straight to the final value.

Comment: @Asher2211 Minor quibble: "...all combinations with *at* *most* only one A...".

Comment: See my answer for a "... *straight* ... *final* *value*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Two cases arise**:

**Case I**: Both the $A$ are selected. In this case, you will choose the remaining (third letter) in $\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways.

**Case II**: In this case, you selected $3$ letters out of the $4$ letters, $A,C,D,E$. You will do this in $\binom{4}{3}=4$ ways.

So, there are $3+4=7$ ways.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

The only over-counting is when there are exactly $2$ A's.  In this case, the over-counting is exactly double.

Therefore, the shortcut is $\displaystyle 
\binom{5}{3} - \binom{3}{1}.$

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! I understand that now. I would upvote your answer because I personally prefer it more but I don't have enough reputation but thank you. What exactly does the 3C1 represent above?

Comment: Let me upvote him on your behalf.

Comment: @SyedArafatQureshi How many ways are there to form a combination that has exactly $2$ A's.  Answer : $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}.$  Therefore, within the $\displaystyle \binom{5}{3}$ enumeration, exactly $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}$ combinations have inappropriately been counted twice.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this, that I think separates the cases clearly, is:

Three cases arise:

1. no $A$ is selected which gives $\binom{3}{3}=1$ selection (all three of $C,D,E$)
2. one $A$ is selected, which gives $\binom{3}{2}=3$ selections (two of $C,D,E$)
3. both $A$s are selected, which gives $\binom{3}{1}=3$ selections (one of $C,D,E$)

This gives $1+3+3=7$ possibilities.